# iOS 12 not showing bluetooth permissions

Tags: ios, bluetooth, permissions

In iOS 12 when looking for the bluetooth permissions requested by the app, I can't seem to find them neither under `Settings > MyApp` nor under `Settings > Privacy > MyApp`.

My app checks permissions using `CBPeripheralManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorized` and lets the user know to update permissions, but users don't seem to find this.
I do have the Info.plist entry for `NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription`.

Unfortunately I don't have an iOS 12 device to test and the simulator does not show the permission either.

Comment: There are no Bluetooth permissions required in iOS 12.  They were introduced in iOS 13.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks, but then `CBPeripheralManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorized` is not true for some reason, what should be expected in this case?

Comment: You should use [the authorisation class var](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbmanager/3377595-authorization) and you will need to guard the check for versions earlier than iOS 13.1. For versions earlier than 13.1 your app is authorised implicitly.